# How to use exact match for a variable value in basename command in unix

Tags: linux, unix, command, special-characters

I have multiple directories with name like:

```
R.201.20.STUDENT_AUS_ESP.2014
R.120.20.STUDENT.US.2013
R.111.21.STUDENT.IND.2014
R.111.21.STUDENT_PAK_ESP.2014
```

I need to get the exact name of the directory
I have the name of the country code in a variable.Example
ctry=US

I am using the below command to get the name of directory

```
basename /Users/myname/Desktop/R*STUDENT*$ctry*
```

but instead of giving the value 'R.120.20.STUDENT.US.2013' it is printing 'R.201.20.STUDENT_AUS_ESP.2014'

I tried to use it like
basename /Users/myname/Desktop/R*STUDENT*[_.]$ctry.*

but the above command does not give any result.

Please help me how to get the above value
I could do it with using 3 time grep command but that does not look good

Comment: What shell are you using? The way you do it works just fine with [Bourne Again Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29).

Comment: I am using bash shell